# PHP blank space error in SQL query statement

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

my first post so go easy please :) I've searched the site for help with this but can't find anything very useful for this situation.

I've a simple PHP/HTML web application using MVC Framework and CodeIgniter that allows a user to select a company from a html select multiple box, and then add information, e.g. rate card information, to an sql database using 2 tables with 1 matching foreign key.

It all works fine if the company name is only one word, but gives database error 1452 when there is spaces in any part of the company name. I've used str_replace() to replace ' ' with '&nbsp' when getting data from the database and vice versa. I've copied error message and code below. Apologies if it's a bit of a mess.

Any help is greatly appreciated, been looking at this for too long :(

Error Message

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1452

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`custDB`.`RateCard`, CONSTRAINT `RateCard_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_comp`) REFERENCES `Company` (`id_comp`))

CALL add_rate('test agreement', '123456', '');

Filename: /home/user/NetBeansProjects/CCP/models/custDB/custdbmodel.php

Line Number: 112
```

Line 112 is the SQL query string in the add_rate() function below

**HTML page view**

```
<b>
<div>
    <label for="Aggrement Link">Agreement Link</label>
    <input type="input" name="createRateAggreement" /><br />
    <label for="Intial Fee">Initial Fee</label>
    <input type="number" name="createRateIntialFee" /><br />
    <?php
    echo "<select multiple=\"multiple\" name=\"createRateComp\">";
    foreach($companies->result() as $row)
    {
        $tempCompName=$row->name_comp;
        $tempCompName=str_replace(' ','&nbsp;',$tempCompName);
        echo "<option value=$tempCompName>$tempCompName</option>";
    }?></select><br><input type="submit" name="ubmit" value="Create New Rate Card" />
</div>
<?b>
```

**Model Functions**

```
public function add_rate()
{               
    $rateAgreementIN=$this->input->post('createRateAggreement');
    $rateIntialFeeIN=$this->input->post('createRateIntialFee');
    $compNameIN=$this->input->post('createRateComp');              

    $compNameIN=  str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", $compNameIN);
    $temp=$this->custDBModel->getCompanyIDBYname_comp($compNameIN)->row();
    $compIDIN=$temp->id_comp;

    $query = $this->db->query('CALL add_rate(\''.$rateAgreementIN.'\', \''.$rateIntialFeeIN.'\', \''.$compIDIN.'\');');
    $query->free_result();
}


public function getCompanyIDBYname_comp($compID)
{
 $query=$this->db->query('CALL getCompanyIDBYname_comp(\''.$compID.'\')');

 $output=$query;

while(mysqli_next_result($this->db->conn_id)) 
{
    if($query = mysqli_store_result($this->db->conn_id))
        {
                mysqli_free_result($query);
        }
}                                  
    return $output;     
}
```

**database stored procedure add_rate**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `add_rate`(IN AGREEin varchar(255), IN INTIALFEEin double, IN IDCOMPin INT(11))

BEGIN

INSERT INTO RateCard (agreementLink_rate, date_rate, intialFee_rate, id_comp) VALUES (AGREEin, CURDATE(), INTIALFEEin, IDCOMPin);
END
```

@alex here's the getCompanyIDBYname_comp stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getCompanyIDBYname_comp`(IN NAMEin varchar(55))
BEGIN
SELECT id_comp
FROM custDB.Company
WHERE name_comp=NAMEin;
END
```

Comment: You have typo within **HTML PAGE VIEW**   `"<option value=$tempCompName` `<-------` must be `value='$tempCompName'`

Comment: @Uchiha: not really. html's forgiving, and quotes are only "required" if the attribute's value has spaces in it. e.g. `value=foo bar` and `value="foo bar"` are two very different things.

Comment: @MarcB but who knows that the variable value could be, so wouldn't it be good practice to put quotes around it?

Comment: @MarcB Isn't OP specifically saying that there is only a problem if the name has a space? Meaning the quotes would be required.

Comment: @MarcB thanks for that explanation but I suppose it should be a good practice to place quotes but none other its been good to have such explanation. Thank you

Comment: @BigRabbit: true enough, but in this case, it's not the problem. OP's getting NOTHING back from that field, otherwise there'd be a partial value in the DB call. most likely `$temp->id_comp` is not what it should be (e.g. it's blank from the get-go).

Comment: @MarcB _OP_ is using the value of `select`  within **MODEL** `$compNameIN=$this->input->post('createRateComp');` `<----------`

Comment: The html tag `select` is multiple. Are you sure that process in correctly, because the response is array? 

remove this `str_replace`.

Comment: could you post your `getCompanyIDBYname_comp`  stored procedure as well please?

Comment: @Alex post the above stored procedure

Comment: @Everyone thanks for all the speedy answers...u guys r brilliant!

Comment: @Krystian have tried this without the str_replace and without the multiple select html tag

Comment: so just rty to `WHERE name_comp= 'NAMEin' ;`

Comment: solution posted for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to fix this problem... I used the preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", '', $string) method on the HTML select multiple box choice to remove all non alphanumeric spaces from the selection chosen by the user, then edited the SQL stored procedure to remove any white spaces from the db table's name_comp column for the search. It's a bit of a workaround but the application is able to handle company names with spaces in them as it should, so everyone's happy here. Thanks for the help :)

Here's the changes I made to the model function add_rate()

```
$compNameIN=  str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", $compNameIN);
```

->

```
$compNameIN=  preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/','', $compNameIN);
```

and the getCompanyBYIDcomp_name stored procedure

```
FROM custDB.Company
WHERE name_comp=NAMEin;
END
```

->

```
FROM custDB.Company comp
WHERE replace(comp.name_comp, ' ', '' )= NAMEin
END
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess, you should change your `getCompanyIDBYname_comp` procedure to something like:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getCompanyIDBYname_comp`(IN NAMEin varchar(55))
BEGIN
    SET @compName = NAMEin ;
    PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT id_comp
        FROM custDB.Company
        WHERE name_comp = ? ;';
    EXECUTE stmt USING @compName;

END
```

Comment: Thanks for the guess...it didnt work alas. On debugging this, I have the string value "test agreement" assigned to $compNameIN in the model function....If I copy that value from the variables window in netbeans and paste directly into MySQL workbench and run the query from there...I got no results. However, if I delete the space between the 2 words and manually enter the space again, the database finds the correct compID for 'test agreement'. Very confusing

Comment: so it seems you just send wrong value? wrong space character? or some invisible characters in addition to space

Comment: not intentionally anyway :( but there's definitely something wrong with the stored string value. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 0):

One does need to use htmlspecialchars() alongwith quotes to accept the value in the input field.

```
 <input type="radio" id="html" name="txt1" value="<?php echo > 
 (htmlspecialchars($txt1)); ?>">
<label for="html"><?php echo $txt1?></label>;
```